# How to send a reverse ARP using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, arp

I'm trying to send a reverse-ARP to a certain MAC, hoping to recieve the matching IP.
how would I write it, (assuming I have a variable called mac1 that holds the given MAC address)?

Comment: I remember that I tried setting the op field to 3 (which is how a real RARP would look if I'm not wrong), but I don't recall receiving any responses because in most OSs they disable this.

Answer (score 2):

An RARP request is similar to an ARP request. You can use:

```
sendp(Ether(dst=ETHER_BROADCAST)/ARP(op=3, hwsrc=mac1, hwdst=mac1))
```

If you want to catch an answer, use `srp` instead of `sendp`. On modern networks, it is unlikely that you get an answer, since RARP has been deprecated in favor of BOOTP/DHCP.